# How to simulate calling a utility function using jest?

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm testing a utility function that returns an integer, I'm trying to simulate calling it, but I can't find the right way to do so even after hours of googling.

I've also tried `spyOn()` and it didn't seem to work.

Authentication.js

```
export function auth(username) {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('@app:id').then((id) => {
    if (id === username) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}
```

Authentication.test.js

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'; // Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import mockAxios from 'axios';
import mockAsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import auth from '../App/Utils/Authorization';

test('should check whether the user whose username is entered as a paramter is the same as the user logged in the application', () => {
  auth = jest.fn();
  expect(auth).toHaveReturned();
  expect(mockAsyncStorage.getItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(mockAsyncStorage.multiRemove).toHaveBeenCalledWith('@app:id');
});
```

I expected a simulation of calling `auth()` and a successful test, instead, I'm getting an error `"auth" is read-only` as an output whenever running `yarn test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reassigning the imported member `auth` and not using `jest.fn()` in the way that is supposed to work. Calling the jest mock function would return undefined, instead with [mockFn.mockImplementation(fn)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockimplementationfn) you could bind your function to the mock and test that it's being called or returning some expecting value.

```
import auth from '../App/Utils/Authorization';

test('Test auth', () => {
    const mockAuth = jest.fn().mockImplementation(auth);
    mockAuth();
    expect(mockAuth).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

You can validate the output of your function checking [mockFn.mock.results](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresults), which stores the results of every call made over your call function.

```
test('when user is provided', () => {
    mockAuth({ user: {id: 'test', name: 'test'} });
    expect(mockAuth).toHaveBeenCalled();

    const result = mockAuth.mock.results[0].value;
    expect(result).toBe(1);
});
```

Comment: This solves most of the problem, but how can I use mocked functions inside a mocked function mock implementation? Specifically speaking, how can I use mocked AsyncStorage functions inside `mockAuth`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your auth function is returning a promise. In that case, you have many examples with asynchronous in the [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async). `expect(result).resolves.toEqual(1)` should work